# Why is Unicode \u{23AF} (⎯) different in iOS 13 vs iOS 12

Tags: unicode, ios13

This is a horizontal line character (`⎯`), and it appears longer for me in iOS 13.

Comment: Different font or font size?

Comment: @rmaddy I don't think so... I seem to be using System 20 in both cases

Comment: "System" isn't a font. Look at the actual font (print the `UIFont` you get). But even if it's the same font family, style, weight, and size, etc., the actual glyphs could have been updated from iOS 12 to 13. I've seen this with a symbol I was using.

Comment: BTW - this really isn't a programming question. This is probably better suited for [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) than here.

Answer (score 0):

It appears System was converting to SFUI Regular on iOS13 and SFUI Display on iOS12